# Existence of isolated atom

Tags: atomic-physics

Can a single atom be isolated (which is not possible yet) in space at far away distances?

I have searched for it that an atom can only be isolated if there is no contact between that atom and other atoms or compounds and also no energy provided to make it possible for that atom to go to exited state.
Therefore I thought for this idea, please throw some light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single atom can be easily isolated using optical traps. A single ion is even easier to trap using electrodes,  and there are many research efforts on developing clocks based on single ions (at NIST (US) and PTB (Germany) for example).

It is in general difficult to keep a single atom isolated indefinitely because of collision with background gas particle in the vacuum chamber, or light scattering from the optical trap. If you simultaneously cool the atom using laser cooling, you may extend its lifetime. But usually collision with background gas particle is strong enough to kick the atom out of the optical trap with typical intensity. For ions, because the Coulomb force is so great, I think you can hold on to them for a very long time despite the background collision.

Comment: But in optical traps light energy will be there and it can provide energy to go to exited state, then atom won't be able to get stable.

Comment: yes, that is how light scattering works, and I mentioned you can add laser cooling to compensate for this heating effect.

Comment: @Ikshita Agarwal, If you are interested in how people actually cool single atoms in an optical tweezer, look up "resolved sideband cooling" or "Raman sideband cooling". This technique is used for both neutral atoms and ions.